# command line runner and job launcher

Tags: spring-batch

When I'm trying to run my job via CommandLineRunner, I get the following error: A JobLauncher must be provided.  Please add one to the configuration.

My Spring Batch Configuration Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfiguration implements BatchConfigurer{

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilders;
    
    
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilders;
    
    
    @Autowired
    AdminAPIClient client;
    
    @Autowired
    AdditionalConfiguration additionalConfiguration;
    
    @Autowired
    EmailSender emailSender;
    
    
    @Autowired
    JobLauncher launcher;
    
    
    public SpringBatchConfiguration() {}
    
    private AdditionalConfiguration config;
    
    public SpringBatchConfiguration(AdditionalConfiguration configuration) {
        this.config = configuration;
    }
    

    
    
    
    @Override
    public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
        factory.setIsolationLevelForCreate(this.getConfiguration().getIsolationLevelForCreate());
        factory.setTablePrefix(this.getConfiguration().getSpringBatchTablePrefix());
        factory.setMaxVarCharLength(1200);
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }


    @Override
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        this.launcher = jobLauncher;
        return jobLauncher;
    }


    @Override
    public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() throws Exception {
        JobExplorerFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    public AdditionalConfiguration getConfiguration() {
        return config;
    }

    public void setConfiguration(AdditionalConfiguration configuration) {
        this.config= configuration;
    }
    
    

    
    @Bean("dateRollForwardJob")
    public Job dateRollForwardJob() {
        return jobBuilders.get("someJob")
                //.preventRestart()
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(rollForwardStep())
                .listener(new DateRollForwardJobListener(emailSender))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step rollForwardStep() {
        return stepBuilders.get(StatementJobs.DATE_ROLLFORWARD_TASK.name())
                .tasklet(dateRollForwardTasklet(client, additionalConfiguration))
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Tasklet dateRollForwardTasklet(AdminAPIClient client, AdditionalConfiguration configuration) {
        return new DateRollForwardTasklet(client, additionalConfiguration);
    }
    
    

}
```

My command line:

```
java -cp <classpath dirs> org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner <<packagename>.SpringBatchConfiguration someJob
```

What am I doing wrong? My Spring boot application class is seperate. When I run through the application class but including a dummy CommandLineRunner bean it works and executes correctly. I'm only getting this error when I'm running via the command line.

Separate question: What is the role of the Spring Boot main application class when running via the command line? I have some annotations on the main class like @EnableRetry - when running through the command line how will these extra annotations kick in? Do I have to have these annotations on the configuration class as well?

Comment: Since you are using Spring Boot, you don't need to run your job with the CommandLineJobRunner. You can run your job with: `java -jar yourjob.jar`. Take a look at the getting started guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/